# Problema selector jQuery vs Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Null]

Hola Comunidad, como pueden ver en la imagen, seleccionando un elemento con jQuery si tiene un valor, pero seleccionándolo con javascript nativo me dice null.

Alguna idea de donde estoy fallando? Desde ya, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente jQuery devuelve un objeto con la colección de elementos que coinciden con el selector. Si ningún elemento coincide con el selector, devuelve igualmente un objeto, aunque sin ningún elemento y la propiedad `length` a 0.

El comportamiento del método `getElementById` no es el mismo. Este método devuelve el elemento del DOM cuyo `id` coincide con el especificado (únicamente debería haber uno, si hay varios devuelve el primero), si no existe ningún elemento con ese `id` devuelve `null`.

Lo que parece que te está pasando es que estás buscando un `id` inexistente y por eso `getElementById` devuelve `null`. Comprueba el objeto devuelto por jQuery, no debería tener elementos y tener la propiedad `length` a 0.

Comment: Asi es Asier, el elemento devuelto por jQuery tiene lenght 0, el tema es que aun asi la funcion trabaja con ese valor devuelto, mientras que con el getElementById al ser null me tira error

Comment: @JuanCarlosApx pero eso es simplemente porque en tu código no contemplas la posibilidad de que la respuesta puede ser null. El método hace lo que debe, buscar el elemento con el id que le indicas y, al no encontrarlo, devuelve null.